# Saving utc offset per user in session variable and refreshing it if user moves to another timezone or the session expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables, utc, timezone-offset

I'm constructing a 30 day calendar on a page (only accessible to logged in users).
This page is accessed by this url and I can't pass in any other parameters like a date or utc offset.

> www.mysite.com/controller/calendar/id

I've built a calendar on the page to the specifications given to me.
The way I fetch the calendar data on the server is by starting with the current day through the next 30 days. In order to do this I need the UTC offset of each user, to make sure I'm getting their local current day and not the local day on the server (UTC).

Solution and problem - I partially solved this by saving the utc offset when the user logs into the site and saved it in a session variable like this -

> System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UtcOffset"] = 100

Now I'm faced with 2 problems -

1. The session expires
2. The user taking a flight or driving and changing time zones (utc offset)

I know one solution would be to save the utc offset for each user in the db, so that if the session expires I can look at the db value instead - don't know if this is a good solution? I'm concerned if the user takes a flight and changes their utc offset without logging out of the site on their laptop?

I know an ajax call to getch the data and pass in the utc would work, but I'm trying to do this with a single get call.

Is making the session variable to never expire a bad idea? Are there any concerns I should have about doing this?

Any advice would be much appreciated?

Comment: Can you refresh/update your user session on every trip on server? So whenever user refresh page, his Utc would change. Anyway, everlasting session is not good idea, you could end up cloggin your server with thousands inactive user session (depends on number of users)

Comment: Have you tried using Local storage? It's not sensitive data so you could store the off set there. You wouldn't have to worry about an extra round trip to the db or the session expiring.

Comment: Have you considered using some custom HTTP header, assuming you can access it later from the server? You can use it to pass the browser's time zone.